# kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I start a docker container to run a Kafka server with

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.99.100 --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

I find the IP address of the Docker container. This is 172.17.0.2 and I can ping this address.

Now I want a producer that sends messages:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='172.17.0.2:9092')

for i in range(100):
    producer.send('foobar', b'hola')

producer.close()
```

However this gives:
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.

How to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2174

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: If you are using Docker for mac, There are certain limitations in networking and some workaround provided for that, see https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds
    - For docker-compose you need to add a `link:`
   Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231883/1475386

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Docker on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: how did you manage to solve this problem? I'm running into the same issue?

Comment: I use: docker run --net=host spotify/kafka

Comment: For me it was happening because I used a space in the topic name. Might be that you are also using an invalid topic name.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error but because my topic name wasn't right/set, same as [python_noob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261501/kafka-errors-kafkatimeouterror-kafkatimeouterror-failed-to-update-metadata-aft#comment92849412_48261501).